# How to make a Proxmox VM autostart with the qm command line tool?

Tags: proxmox

How do I make a VM boot on startup using just the `qm` command line tool? I don't want to log in to the GUI, just to be able to set autoboot using SSH.

Answer (score 5):

`qm set $VMID --onboot 1`

where $VMID is the numeric ID of your virtual machine. Obtained with `qm list`.